# How to design a topped-up internal balance for a replicated API?

Tags: api, distributed-system, billing

My product is an API which charges an amount of USD every N requests.
I would like to allow my users to top-up their internal balances through PayPal, then decrease their balances when they use the API.

I'm using Kong (+Cassandra) as API gateway in a Kubernetes cluster, so the Kong instance reached by the same user may be different for every request.

I would like to:

- show a relatively up-to-date balance on the user dashboard
- do not allow users to have a negative balance (or just a bit for technical reason)
- do not slow down the response by requesting/updating the remaining balance (ie. the database) at every request

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You are between a rock and a hard place.

I would suggest a combination of approaches.

1. Make the users session sticky. So that multiple requests hit the same server

   This way you can get a 'remaining credit' at the start of a session, and then just keep track in memory
2. Inserts to the db on each call should be fast. So you can keep an uptodate count of api class made by inserting individual rows rather than updating a row.

Comment: I can't do session affinity

Comment: can you shard the database?

Comment: At the end it will be a Kong plugin. I don't think so.